# How can I prove that $(X \times Y) \cap (Z \times T) = (X \cap Z)\times(Y \cap T)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this problem that I'm trying to figure for more than an hour and I just can't even start it. 
Is someone able to help me? Any help is much appreciated!!

PROBLEM:
How can I prove that $(X \times Y) \cap (Z \times T) = (X \cap Z)\times(Y \cap T)$

Comment: "I just can't even start it". Start for proving that $A=B$: let $x\in A$ and prove that $x\in B$. Secondly  let $x\in B$ and prove that $x\in A$.

Comment: Hint: What does an element of $(X\times Y)$ look like?  What does an element of $(X\cap Z)\times (Y\cap T)$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,b) \in (X \times Y) \cap (Z \times T) \iff$

$a\in (X \cap Z)$ and $b\in Y\cap T\iff$

$(a,b)\in (X \cap Z)\times(Y \cap T)$